# Default umask 077 not applied at session start

Tags: linux-mint, login, pam, umask

I cannot get the default umask for a session to be `0077`.

I have edited `/etc/login.defs` and set the value to `077` there:

```
UMASK           077
```

Also I've made sure the following entry exists in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session optional                        pam_umask.so
```

While this configuration seems to work when the user logs in using `su` it doesn't when the login happens through mdm. Both mdm and su configuration files in pam.d include common-session.

```
username@hostname ~ $ umask
0022
username@hostname ~ $ su username
Password:
username@hostname ~ $ umask
0077
```

This problem does not occur when using GDM or LIGHTDM instead of MDM.

Any ideas on what could be a possible cause of this?

Comment: Maybe the directive needs to be in another pam module as well.

Comment: @mdpc I have no idea what module you could possibly mean. Above the said entry in `common-session` a comment says that the umask value is read from `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: Check the home directories of these users; where is the server from? Do they have `.bashrc` files that set their umask? How do these users login? Through VNC or locally on the machine? You might also check `.xinitrc` for both the local logins and VNC; some distributions have umask setting there.

Comment: Check if there is something in `/etc/profile` or any of the other files the shell sources on startup.

Comment: @vonbrand I've checked all of those possibilities. I even did a `grep umask` on all of /etc to see if there is something still on 022.

Comment: @Bichoy I've checked my current user and a for new user. su works, mdm doesn't. There is nothing in `/etc/skel` to point to 022. Login is locally on the machine.

Comment: I just found https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1094990 could be related.

Comment: Is your root prompt set to use `$`? Because that `su` command really switches to the root user, not yourself.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling for privacy information I have tried to omit username and hostname. I have updated it accordingly now. Sorry for the confusion it has caused.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer your question but this technique might help you shed some light on if there's a stray `umask` command being run somewhere as part of your shell's config files:

```
$ bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep 'umask'
```

- `-x` -> enable debugging
- `-l` -> login shell
- `-i` -> interactive shell
- `-c` -> command

The `exit` is necessary so that the shell returns once it's done.

#### example

```
$ bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep umask
+ umask 002
$
```

I found the above technique over in this U&L Q&A titled: [How to test for possible conflicts while using alias in bashrc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52161/how-to-test-for-possible-conflicts-while-using-alias-in-bashrc/52166#52166).